# Vector vs Array for large number of elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

I have a text file with about 1000 values (strings, to be precise), each of which has a key attached to it. The keys are not necessarily unique (that is, there can be 5 values with the same key). I am creating a program that organizes this data into a tree such that each node of the tree is organized by it's key, storing a list of that key's associated in the node.

I do not know how many values per key I can expect - it would probably be from 1 to 5, thereabouts.

Also, once the values are stored, I will not need to perform any changes on them. I will only need to read them.

My question is this:

From a memory-usage standpoint, would it make more sense to use vectors or arrays (of size 5) to store the values?

Using the vectors would mean that I would only need to store as many as I needed. However using an array would mean I don't have to use the vector object. I'm not sure which one would be more efficient.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: can you specify more what is memory-usage criterion? is this size in memory or speed or some combination maybe?

Comment: How would you be able to store the values with non-unique keys without an array/vector/other type of container?

Comment: I think OP means a vector of vectors i.e.

Comment: @computer I thought he was saying a tree with key->vector nodes, as opposed to a tree of key->strings

Comment: well to be honest at the moment I don't get what OP wants, he should be more precise it looks as if he asked question and went to sleep

Comment: 1000 items is not "a large number" in most environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider C++11's `std::array`, it is faster, smaller than `std::vector` and safer than `array[]` for your particular case.