# Segmentation fault(core dumped) error while executing code for N >= 10^7

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to write a code for the problem [Bytelandian gold coins](https://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS) of codeChef. The code works fine for `n < 10^7` but gives segmentation error for higher values. I looked for [datatypes which could hold bigger numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-data-types/) but that too didn't work. I certainly think that there's no problem in my code but maybe the recursion tree becomes too large for the compiler to handle. Here's the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define lli long long int

lli divide(lli n, lli dp[])
{
    lli ans = 0;

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    if (dp[n] != 0)
        return dp[n];

    lli m1 = floor(divide(n / 2, dp));
    lli m2 = floor(divide(n / 3, dp));
    lli m3 = floor(divide(n / 4, dp));
    lli sum = m1 + m2 + m3;
    ans = max(sum, n);
    dp[n] = ans;
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        lli n;
        cin >> n;
        lli dp[n + 1] = { 0 };
        lli ans = divide(n, dp);
        cout << ans << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you imagine that computers have infinite resources?

Comment: VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) is a C-feature and not legal C++. You're overflowing the stack. Use a `std::vector<lli>`. Also `<bits/stdc++.h>` is no standard header and should be avoided.

Comment: `lli dp[n + 1] = {0};` -- Competitive coding nonsense in one line.  Crazy macros, non-standard VLA usage, etc.

Comment: @Abhishek Any recursive function will exhaust stack space eventually if not limited in how many times it's called and 10^7 is a good way to find that limit.

Comment: It is mentioned on the site that N can be up to 10^9. I am afraid that some  additional work must be done at the algorithm level

Comment: This problem seems deigned to make a recursive solution both obvious and unworkable. Write an iterative solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think in this line a large array is allocated on stack:

```
lli dp[n + 1] = {0};
```

This is likely the cause of the segfault. You may want to change it to `std::vector`. For example:

```
std::vector<lli> dp(n + 1, 0);
```

Alternatively you could perhaps make it static or allocate it with `new[]` (perhaps just once for all tests, to minimize the overhead, and in this you need to remember to clean it up properly with `delete[]`).

Comment: *allocate it with new* – please don't advertise using `new[]`.

Comment: @sbarzowski But I'd still have to create a vector of N dimensions. I mean I simply don't have to push_back() but I got to store values in the vector in some Kth palce and a lot of indices might be still empty. In short don't you think creating a vector would still take the same amount of space as arrays?

Comment: @Swordfish I think using `new[]` *is* a valid way to solve, but yes it's not ideal, and in pretty any "real" codebase I would push using vectors instead. This is a codechef exercise though, so learning about various ways to approach this (and even getting burned by some) is sort of the point I guess. I changed my answer to emphasize the better solution.

Comment: @Abhishek It's not about the total amount of space, but about how it is allocated. In particular using a vector results in keeping just a pointer, length, capacity and maybe some other things like that on stack and the actual data is allocated on heap.

Comment: @sbarzowski *I think using new[] is a valid way to solve* – `std::make_unique<>()` ftw.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @sbarzowski, when you do

```
lli dp[n+1] = {0}
```

you are asking for a memory allocation on the stack. Allocating memory on the stack, though results in faster access time but results in shortage of memory. Instead, use memory allocation on the heap. 
For this, you can use the `new` operator. For detailed explanation on stack vs heap allocation, check: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/

Further, it is advised to use `std::vector` or `std::array` when dealing with large number of elements that are to be stored together. References: [Vector vs Array for large number of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072820/vector-vs-array-for-large-number-of-elements)